How can I read the incoming request headers in my Vue 3 app?
I'm prototyping a Vue 3 application that will be deployed to a Kubernetes environment the web traffic that reaches the web app contains the JWT in the request headers. Authn and authz are handled outside of the app, a layer above, as I like to think of it.
Prior to this Vue 3 app, I was using Flask 3 and was easily able to inspect every request's headers and inspect the JWT and decide if users had access, etc. My problem is that I cannot find a way to inspect the incoming requests in Vue 3. My Vue 3 app is using vue-router.
I tried using the vue-router "beforeEach" mechanism but cannot find a way to view the request details.
Is there a way I can view JWT info that is in request headers in my Vue 3 app?


Vue is a frontend framework. It can make requests and receive/inspect responses. If you're inspecting incoming request headers, you're talking about a backend, which Vue is not.

Well, I am assuming by flask 3, you meant it was used in a traditional server side rendered application where backend and frontend resides in a single app. The flow and mental model is completely different there. In case of SPA built with Vue, the frontend and backend are completely isolated and usually communicate via AJAX/fetch. So, in your case, your Vue app should be sending the headers in a request while your backend should be receiving and processing them.

Flask is server side rendered, while Vuue3 is client side. If the JWT is stored in a http-only-cookie (a common and safe alternative), you cannot access it client side. This protects you from having malicious javascript or viruses on the client stealing your JWT, so that is by design.
